# argument "variable" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

When tried to use `crPlot()` function in `car` package, I had encountered this error:

```
m1 <- lm(socst ~ read+write, data=hsb2)
crPlot(m1)
```

> Error in crPlot.lm(m1) : argument "variable" is missing, with no default

And the same error happens with `avPlot()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> S3 method for lm crPlot(model, variable, id=FALSE,
>       order=1, line=TRUE, smooth=TRUE, 
>       col=carPalette()[1], col.lines=carPalette()[-1],
>       xlab, ylab, pch=1, lwd=2, grid=TRUE, ...)
>
> variable: A quoted string giving the name of a variable for the horizontal axis.

Also, you should generally use 'crPlots', not 'crPlot'.

Comment: Thank you. But I find people simply use patterns like crPlot(modelObject) instead of typically assigning values to the 'variable', why couldn't I do so?

Comment: are you sure they're using `crPlot` and not `crPlots` (note the "s" at the end)? It's actually the latter that should be generally used.

Comment: Great to hear! I updated the answer above. Please accept it. Thanks!